# Remove duplicated from Pandas dataframe based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a Pandas grouped dataset which looks like below:

```
test_identifier timestamp   Count_of_Fail_tests test_status
test1   22-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        23-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        24-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        25-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        26-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
test10  22-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        23-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        24-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        25-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        26-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
test2   22-08-2022 07:00    2   fail
        23-08-2022 07:00    2   pass
        24-08-2022 07:00    2   pass
        25-08-2022 07:00    2   fail
        26-08-2022 07:00    2   pass
test3   22-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        23-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        24-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        25-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        26-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
test4   22-08-2022 07:00    1   pass
        23-08-2022 07:00    1   pass
        24-08-2022 07:00    1   pass
        25-08-2022 07:00    1   pass
        26-08-2022 07:00    1   fail
```

I want to sort or remove duplicates for the `Count_of_Fail_tests` column so that, the output looks like below:

```
test_identifier timestamp   Count_of_Fail_tests test_status
test1   22-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        23-08-2022 07:00        pass
        24-08-2022 07:00        pass
        25-08-2022 07:00        pass
        26-08-2022 07:00        pass
test10  22-08-2022 07:00        pass
        23-08-2022 07:00        pass
        24-08-2022 07:00        pass
        25-08-2022 07:00        pass
        26-08-2022 07:00        pass
test2   22-08-2022 07:00    2   fail
        23-08-2022 07:00        pass
        24-08-2022 07:00        pass
        25-08-2022 07:00        fail
        26-08-2022 07:00        pass
test3   22-08-2022 07:00    0   pass
        23-08-2022 07:00        pass
        24-08-2022 07:00        pass
        25-08-2022 07:00        pass
        26-08-2022 07:00        pass
test4   22-08-2022 07:00        pass
        23-08-2022 07:00        pass
        24-08-2022 07:00        pass
        25-08-2022 07:00        pass
        26-08-2022 07:00    1   fail
```

If the column `test_status` is removed that also ok.Basically the goal is to find number of failed  runs for each testcases per day

**Original Dataframe:**

```
    timestamp   test_identifier test_status
0   22-08-2022 07:00    test1   pass
1   22-08-2022 07:00    test2   fail
2   22-08-2022 07:00    test3   pass
3   22-08-2022 07:00    test4   pass
4   22-08-2022 07:00    test5   pass
5   22-08-2022 07:00    test6   pass
6   22-08-2022 07:00    test7   fail
7   22-08-2022 07:00    test8   pass
8   22-08-2022 07:00    test9   pass
9   22-08-2022 07:00    test10  pass
10  23-08-2022 07:00    test1   pass
11  23-08-2022 07:00    test2   pass
12  23-08-2022 07:00    test3   pass
13  23-08-2022 07:00    test4   pass
14  23-08-2022 07:00    test5   fail
15  23-08-2022 07:00    test6   pass
16  23-08-2022 07:00    test7   pass
17  23-08-2022 07:00    test8   pass
18  23-08-2022 07:00    test9   pass
19  23-08-2022 07:00    test10  pass
20  24-08-2022 07:00    test1   pass
21  24-08-2022 07:00    test2   pass
22  24-08-2022 07:00    test3   pass
23  24-08-2022 07:00    test4   pass
24  24-08-2022 07:00    test5   pass
25  24-08-2022 07:00    test6   pass
26  24-08-2022 07:00    test7   pass
27  24-08-2022 07:00    test8   pass
28  24-08-2022 07:00    test9   pass
29  24-08-2022 07:00    test10  pass
30  25-08-2022 07:00    test1   pass
31  25-08-2022 07:00    test2   fail
32  25-08-2022 07:00    test3   pass
33  25-08-2022 07:00    test4   pass
34  25-08-2022 07:00    test5   pass
35  25-08-2022 07:00    test6   pass
36  25-08-2022 07:00    test7   fail
37  25-08-2022 07:00    test8   pass
38  25-08-2022 07:00    test9   pass
39  25-08-2022 07:00    test10  pass
40  26-08-2022 07:00    test1   pass
41  26-08-2022 07:00    test2   pass
42  26-08-2022 07:00    test3   pass
43  26-08-2022 07:00    test4   fail
44  26-08-2022 07:00    test5   pass
45  26-08-2022 07:00    test6   pass
46  26-08-2022 07:00    test7   pass
47  26-08-2022 07:00    test8   pass
48  26-08-2022 07:00    test9   pass
49  26-08-2022 07:00    test10  pass
```

Comment: please provide the constructor of your input for clarity (i.e. code to generate the object)

Comment: `new_df = df.set_index(["test_identifier", "timestamp"]).sort_index()
new_df2=(new_df.test_status.eq('fail')
                   .groupby(level=0)
                   .sum()
                   .to_frame('Count_of_Fail_tests')
                   .join(new_df))`

Comment: Added original dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the desired results. It will hid all the "passes" from your df and only count the fails per date/test paring

```
df.mask(df['test_status'].eq('pass')).groupby(['timestamp', 'test_identifier'], as_index = False)['test_status'].count()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This will be used in my source original df?

Comment: I believe so, if I understand your question. I used the data you provided when making the above code.